# Github Desktop, how to import projects into Android Studio

Tags: android, github, import

The title says it all. I have recently downloaded Github Desktop in my belief that it would be easier to import projects into android studio. However, I have not found a way to do that. Any suggestions?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if you may have tried this or where you are in the process, but the best way I've seen to  import an existing Android project is to import it via the build.gradle. If you already have a project open in Android Studiuo, your're going to want to go to File->Close Project and then from the "Welcome to Android Studio" screen click "Import project(Eclipse ADT, Gradle etc)" and then navigate to your project's build.gradle.